# f:ajax don't fired with event "change"

Tags: ajax, jsf, datepicker, jquery-multidatespicker

The code:

```
<h:inputText id="date" value="#{holidayRequestController.dates}">
                    <f:ajax execute="date" event="change"
                        listener="#{holidayRequestController.generateDates}"
                        render="generateDate" />
</h:inputText>
<h:panelGroup id="generateDate" class="span8"> ..</h:panelGroup>
```

With this code when i  using date picker to select a date in from h:inputText, and f:ajax will fire event and populate this date to generateDate component.
But when i change to multiDatePicker, f:ajax don't fired with event "change"(although it work with event "blur", but i have some problem to use "blur").
**What should i do to use event "change" for multiDatePicker?** 
One other question: **is there support f:ajax for tag h:inputHidden in jsf?**

Thanks for support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can happen if the `change` event is actually not fired. That can in turn happen if the input element's value is only manipulated via JavaScript and not via enduser interaction.

Basically, when JavaScript manipulates the value via `element.value = newValue`, and you want the `change` event to be fired, then the JavaScript should explicitly call `element.change()` on the input element being manipulated.

According to [`$.multiDatesPicker` documentation](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/), you can use the `onSelect` option to hook a function on select. In that function you can then just call `element.change()`. So, given an input as follows:

```
<h:inputText ... styleClass="multi-dates" />
```

then you can achieve it as follows:

```
$(".multi-dates").multiDatesPicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        $(this).change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello BalusC, I still have problem when i reclick on dates which is selected. EX: i choose three dates: 1,2 and 3 then i reclick on date 1 then ajax event fired, i reclick on date 2 then ajax event fired too but when i relicked on date 3 ajax is not fired. Same result when i reclick on 3 date same time. Can you help to explain what it mean?

Comment: Apparently the value has not changed.

Comment: Only the last date ajax is not fired, the other still well. I have used query console to check value of date field and it empty. I also use debug to check $(this).change() is run. Why ajax event is not fire in case date field empty?